# How to retrieve data from firebase using key?

Tags: android, firebase

```
"sicknessEntries" : [ null, {
    "daysSick" : 1,
    "sickness" : "Flu",
    "type" : "Viral",
    "userId" : "K9lPzGCb1AUdNqNywurwNueunv42"
}, 
-K9lP-zGCb1AUdNqNywurwN {
    "daysSick" : 2,
    "sickness" : "Pneumonia",
    "type" : "Bacterial",
    "userId" : "abcd"
}, 
-NywurwNueunv42 {
    "daysSick" : 1,
    "severity" : "Medium",
    "sickness" : "Shingles",
    "type" : "Viral",
    "userId" : "user123"
}, 
{
    "daysSick" : 1,
    "severity" : "Medium",
    "sickness" : "Flu",
    "type" : "Viral",
    "userId" : "K9lPzGCb1AUdNqNywurwNueunv42"
} ]
```

For the above json it shows different type of child i have to retrieve only value of the key "sickness" whether it is in the direct child or in the sub child?

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot friendSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(friendSnapshot.child("sickness").getValue());
        }
    }
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

If i use the above code it can get only the main child values for the key "sickness" (i.e. it returns the both Flu, Flu only not the others). But i have to get all the sub child values too which have the same key. How to retrieve it?

Comment: k then how to retrieve data from the above? If it is not json? what is that may i know? I have given the part of the json only

Answer (score 1):

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference refUsers = database.getReference("/childname");
            refUsers.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    try {
                        Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.child("sicknessEntries").getChildren();
                        List<SickModel> sickList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (DataSnapshot child : children) {
                            SickModel sickmodel = child.getValue(SickModel.class);
                            sickList.add(sickmodel);
                        }
```

Try the above code snippet,for retrieving array of sickmodel.
Where sickmodel has daysSick ,sickness,type,userId